# how does liftM (:[]) work

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand the expression below. It converts the list of characters `['a','b','c']` to a list of strings `["a", "b", "c"]`

```
liftM (:[]) "abc"
```

How does this happen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Function `liftM` turns a function which takes input and produces output to a function which takes input in some monad and produces output in the same monad. Lets look at its definition:

```
liftM :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
liftM f mx = mx >>= \x -> return (f x)
```

Strings in Haskell are lists of characters (`type String = [Char]`), so

```
"abc" = ['a', 'b', 'c'] :: [Char]
```

From your application compiler infers `a = Char`, `b = [Char]`, `m a = [Char]`, `m = []`. So `m b = [[Char]] = [String]`. List is a monad where `return x = [x]` and `(>>=) = concatMap`. So if we specialize above definition we get:

```
liftM f mx = concatMap (\x -> [f x]) mx
```

And if we apply the arguments we get:

```
concatMap (\x -> [[x]]) ['a', 'b', 'c'] =
concat $ map (\x -> [[x]]) ['a', 'b', 'c'] =
concat $ [[['a']], [['b']], [['c']]] =
[['a'], ['b'], ['c']] =
["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: and `concatMap (\x -> [f x])` is `map f`.

Answer (score 14):

The robotic monkey head operator `(:[])` is just the [section](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator) of the list cons `(:)` and the empty list `[]`, i.e. `(:[])` is equivalent to `(\x -> x:[])`; which in turn can also be written using list syntax as `(\x -> [x])`.

Rewritten this way, we have

```
liftM (\x -> [x]) "abc"
```

The string literal `"abc"` is also just syntax sugar for the [character list `['a', 'b', 'c']`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Lists_and_tuples#Strings_are_just_lists), so we can in turn rewrite the above as

```
liftM (\x -> [x]) ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

[`liftM` is just `fmap` from the Dark Days when `Functor` wasn't a superclass of `Monad`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463500/why-do-we-have-map-fmap-and-liftm), giving

```
fmap (\x -> [x]) ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

The `Functor` instance of `[]` sets `fmap = map`, giving

```
map (\x -> [x]) ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

which reduces to

```
[['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
```

Or, going back to string notation

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

Q.e.d.

Comment: +1 for the "robotic monkey operator" I've never heard the term and from now on my haskell programming experience will be even more awesome!

Answer (score 8):

`liftM` is equivalent to `fmap`, only specialised to monads. `(:[])` uses `(:)` to make a function that produces lists of one element. Just like `(+2)` is a compact way of writing `(\x -> x + 2)`, `(:[])` is equivalent to `(\x -> x : [])`, or `(\x -> [x])`.

Your expression, then, might have been written as:

```
fmap (\x -> [x]) "abc"
```

The existence of `liftM` reflects the fact that any legitimate `Monad` can be made into a `Functor` by doing `fmap f m = m >>= \x -> return (f x)`. You can always replace `liftM` by `fmap`, so the only reasons to use it are:

- to define `fmap` for free if you already have a `Monad` instance (and don't want to use the `DeriveFunctor` GHC extension), and
- an entirely optional style choice (if you are writing obviously monadic code and feel that `liftM` looks better than `fmap`).

Comment: whow, thanks! where do I learn more about all this? so that I can also easily use terms such as "existence of liftM reflects the fact that any legitimate Monad can be made into a Functor"? : )

Comment: @akonsu By "legitimate", I mean one which follows the monad laws. A brief introduction to them is [the second half of the "Understanding monads" Wikibook chapter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads#Monad_Laws). One thing it doesn't mention is that, for any type constructor, all implementations of `fmap` that follow the [first *functor* law](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/The_Functor_class#The_functor_laws), `fmap id = id`, are necessarily (and automatically) equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

`liftM` is defined as:

```
liftM f m = m >>= \x -> return (f x)
```

We're using `liftM` with a list (of characters), so we need to look at the list instance of `Monad` to see how `>>=` and `return` are defined:

```
instance Monad [] where
    return x = [x]
    xs >>= f = concat (map f xs)
```

Thus

```
liftM f xs = xs >>= \x -> return (f x)
           = concat (map (\x -> [f x]) xs)
```

The `concat` on the outside and the `[ ]` on the inside cancel each other out, so

```
liftM f xs = map (\x -> f x) xs
           = map f xs
```

In other words, `liftM` in the list monad is simply `map`.

```
map (:[]) ['a', 'b', 'c'] = [(: []) 'a', (: []) 'b', (: []) 'c']
                          = ['a' : [], 'b' : [], 'c' : []]
                          = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
                          = ["a","b","c"]
```

because a string is really just a list of characters.